# AngularJS transform the displayed model Property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I a have a `Person` witch has visited some `Cities`...

```
Person {name: John, cities: [15, 24, 13]}
```

I have also a function `GetNames(cityIds)` that transforms `[15, 24, 13]` to `['Paris', 'New-York', 'Tokyo']`;

Now having `<div>{{person.cities}}</div>` I will obtain `<div>15, 24, 13</div>`;

Is there a way to use the `GetNames` to obtain `<div>'Paris', 'New-York', 'Tokyo'</div>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `GetNames()` is a function in the scope of your controller
`$scope.Getnames()` you could do:

```
<div>{{GetNames(person.cities)}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ng-repeat` directive.

```
<div>
    <span ng-repeat="city in GetNames(person.cities)">
       {{city}}<span ng-if="!$last">,</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Notice that I use the `$last` special property of the `ng-repeat` directive combined with the `ng-if` directive to prevent a comma appearing at the end of the list.

To learn more about the `ng-repeat` directive visit the [AngularJS ngRepeat API Reference Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat); `ng-if`, the [AngularJS ngIf API Reference Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Comment: what is the difference between `ng-repeat='city in GetNames(person.cities)'` and `<div>{{GetNames(person.cities)}}</div>` approaches?

Comment: Your user sees either `Paris, London, New York` or `["Paris","London","New York"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling controller function like this

```
<div>{{GetNames(person.cities)}}</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.GetNames = function(cityIds) {
     // Write logic here for transformation cityIds to city string
    return strCities; // It should contain your cities string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a less cluttered template:

```
{{GetNames(person.cities) | myToString}}
```

Make a custom filter:

```
angular.module("myApp").filter("myToString", function() {
    return function(input) {
        var out = "";
        for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
            out += input[i];
            if (i != input.length-1) {
                out += ", ";
            };
        };
        return out;
    };
});
```